# Windows 8 and modern IE - List running downloads

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

This one bugs me,

if I use the Modern Internet Explorer and download a file I can choose save and get a new Dialog at the bottom with the download progress and the buttons `Cancel` and `Close`

If I choose `Close` the download continues in the background and after a while I get a notification that the download is finished.

However I can't figure out how to view the download status again. I can only download another file and get the progress bar again showing the aggregated download time for both downloads.

Is there any hidden shortcut or other possibilty to show the downloads?

The desktop version has a Shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to show the download manager but modern IE downloads are not shown in this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a problem faced by other users as well and there is no solution. This problem has been discussed on the Microsoft Community at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie-10-metro-download-list/086c8b86-ab27-4a82-b8a0-6d895cb06f63